# Magento 2 Front End File Upload document location

Tags: magento2.4, magento-commerce, file-uploader

I have added a link to upload files for a product to be fabricated via our Magento 2.4 (self hosted commerce) website. However, I've been stumped on where these files live so I can clean them out after some time so the server doesn't fill up. I'm using the native Product: Custom Option: type: File Upload.

Any help on the path to finding these files so I can do regular flushing / archiving would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.